# Confusion with data after scipy.fftconvolve

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft

This question has probably been asked before but I cannot find my specific answer in any one place. So here it is: I am trying to find the time difference (lag) between two audio signals (Gaussian white noise) that have been captured by two USB mics. With no problem I have recorded the audio from two different streams, saved them and read the data back to an array. Next, I have experimented with a few different methods for finding the delay: taking the FFT first then cross correlating, `scipy.fftconvole`, zero-padding, and it seems countless other methods/strategies. As a test to confirm my calculated delay I tried to use that time delay to calculate the speed of sound. With a mic spacing of .6 meters I should get a time delay of 1.728 ms (v = dis / time). I convolve the mics recordings with the source signal, I am unsure what to do with the peak values I get from the `fftconvolve`. From these values I should be able to compute my time difference? Any help you can give would be excellent.

Reading data:

```
samprat_1, data_1 = scipy.io.wavfile.read(sin_tone_1)   
samprat_2, data_2 = scipy.io.wavfile.read(sin_tone_2)
samrat_tone_played, data_tone_played = scipy.io.wavfile.read(sin_tone_played)
```

Convolving:

```
data_1 = _1_
data_2 = _2_
_tp_ = data_tone_played
convol_1_wsig = signal.fftconvolve(_1_, _tp_[::-1], "full")
convol_2_wsig = signal.fftconvolve(_2_, _tp_[::-1], "full")
```

Also here is the plot of the FFTconvolve result:

[image: FFTconvolve]

Comment: Just to make sure, if you take a look at a small part of the signals (like, in a plot), can you _see_ that one is a time-delayed version of the other? Since you're using two different physical microphones, the correspondence isn't going to be exact; each microphone introduces its own random noise. So unless there are very obvious distinguishing features in the signal (like loud and soft spots), there's no hope of finding the time delay in the first place.

Comment: There are a few problems here: 1) you should use "cross-correlation" instead of convolution (or is that the `::-1` here -- it's impossible to tell?); 2) what are `_1_`, `_tp_`; etc. It seems you're trying to do 6 steps in a row, look at the result, and guess which step didn't work. Instead you need to make sure the first step works before moving onto the second.  For example, before doing the cross-correlation (or convolution) you should subtract the mean, but you'll only figure that out by paying attention to that step.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for http://dsp.stackexchange.com/  Once you understand the mathematical algorithm, you might find it easy to implement.  If you run into trouble implementing it, then ask here.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, I thought so too (about dsp.stackexchange) but after working out a solution, there’s a major code-related stumbling block, so I’m happy op came here first.

Comment: Add the `signal-processing` tag.

Comment: Thankk you guys for the responses. I added the few lines of code that will probably clarify things. I will also post this question with the signal-processing tag. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this, it’s a good idea to make sure your algorithm works on perfect data before trying with real data. It turns out that even if you understand the algorithm, Scipy is stupid in not giving an easy way to obtain the lags corresponding to correlations.

So here’s my [little script](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/d089d5b5b71601b5e8d563cc693f64db): I generate two signal vectors of unequal lengths, but both containing a specific signal (a linear chirp) with *known* delays (0.1 and 0.2 seconds respectively). Then I use both `scipy.signal.correlate` and `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` to make sure I can recover the correct delay between the two signals. This boils down to generating the vector of lags (i.e., the time vector that corresponds to the indexes of the correlation) correctly, and knowing how to interpret them.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal
import numpy.fft as fft
try:
    import pylab
except ImportError:
    print("Can't import pylab, do you have matplotlib installed?")

## Generator for the ideal underlying signal
# Parameters for a linear chirp that lasts 0.5 seconds, over which the frequency
# is swept from -10 Hz to 5 Hz.
signalLength = 0.5 # seconds
fStart = -10.0 # Hz
fEnd = +5.0 # Hz
fRate = (fEnd - fStart) / signalLength
# `x` is a function that evaluates this underlying signal for any given time
# vector `t`.
x = lambda t: (np.sin(2 * np.pi * (fStart + fRate * 0.5 * t) * t) *
               np.logical_and(t >= 0, t<signalLength))

## Generate some test data
fs = 100.0 # Sample rate, Hz

# First signal: lasts 2 seconds, sampled at `fs` Hz
Tend = 2.0 # seconds
t1 = np.arange(0, Tend, 1/fs)
y1 = x(t1 - 0.1)
# Plot?
try:
    pylab.figure()
    pylab.subplot(211)
    pylab.plot(t1, y1)
except NameError:
    pass

# Second signal: lasts 1 second, also sampled at `fs` Hz
t2 = np.arange(0, Tend/2, 1/fs)
y2 = x(t2 - 0.2)
try:
    pylab.plot(t2, y2)
    pylab.legend(['y1', 'y2'])
except NameError:
    pass

## Correlate
# Evaluate the correlation
z = signal.correlate(y1, y2)
# And this is crucial: the vector of lags for which the above `z` corresponds
# to.
tz = (np.arange(z.size) - (y2.size - 1)) / fs
# Here's how to evaluate the relative delay between y1 and y2
print('y1 is y2 delayed by {} seconds'.format(tz[np.argmax(np.abs(z))]))
try:
    pylab.subplot(212)
    pylab.plot(tz, z)
except NameError:
    pass

## Correlate with flipped y1-vs-y2 to make sure it still works
z = signal.correlate(y2, y1)
# Note that now, we subtract `y1.size` because `y1` is second argument to
# `correlate`
tz = (np.arange(z.size) - (y1.size - 1)) / fs
print('y2 is y1 delayed by {} seconds'.format(tz[np.argmax(np.abs(z))]))
try:
    pylab.subplot(212)
    pylab.plot(tz, z)
    pylab.legend(['correlate(y1,y2)', 'correlate(y2,y1)'])
except NameError:
    pass
```

This generates (see bottom for figure):

```
y1 is y2 delayed by -0.1 seconds
y2 is y1 delayed by 0.1 seconds
```

Hooray! Ok! So we know that if you `correlate(y1, y2)`, to generate the vector of lags `tz`, you subtract `y2`’s length. And we understand that in this case, the maximum magnitude-correlation happens at a lag that means “how much to delay `y2` to get `y1`”.

Let’s wrap this up into some functions for general purpose reuse. The function won’t know about sampling rate, so it’ll just return integer-lags, but we can divide by the sample rate outside.

```
## Wrap this in a function
def correlateWithLags(y1, y2, *args, **kwargs):
    "Returns `scipy.signal.correlate` output as wel as vector of lags"
    z = signal.correlate(y1, y2, *args, **kwargs)
    lags = np.arange(z.size) - (y2.size - 1)
    return (z, lags)

# Make sure all works as above
(z, nz) = correlateWithLags(y1, y2)
tz = nz / fs
print('y1 is y2 delayed by {} seconds: `correlateWithLags`'.format(tz[np.argmax(np.abs(z))]))
```

This generates:

```
y1 is y2 delayed by -0.1 seconds: `correlateWithLags`
```

Still working!

Now for funsies, let’s replace `scipy.signal.correlate` with `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`. This can greatly reduce runtime with long signal lengths. Correlation is the same as convolution except you have to time-reverse one of the signals, but after taking care of that little detail, the results should be exactly the same, and the mechanics of generating the correct delay is the same as above.

```
## Use `fftconvolve` instead of `correlate` for fast-convolution
def fftCorrelateWithLags(y1, y2, *args, **kwargs):
    "Equivalent to correlateWithLags but uses `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`"
    # NOTA BENE: reverse `y2`! And if complex, need `np.conj(y2)` too!
    z = signal.fftconvolve(y1, y2[::-1], *args, **kwargs)
    lags = np.arange(z.size) - (y2.size - 1)
    return (z, lags)

# Make sure it still works
(z, nz) = fftCorrelateWithLags(y1, y2)
tz = nz / fs
print('y1 is y2 delayed by {} seconds: `fftCorrelateWithLags`'.format(tz[np.argmax(np.abs(z))]))
```

Still works:

```
y1 is y2 delayed by -0.1 seconds: `fftCorrelateWithLags`
```

Scipy’s `correlate` really should give you a function that returns the vector of lags corresponding to the correlation. For this reason, I think it’s ok to have posted this on StackOverflow instead of http://dsp.stackexchange.com because even if you understood the algorithm, you’d still have code-bullshittery to deal with .

Postscript. Here’s the [full code in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/d089d5b5b71601b5e8d563cc693f64db). Here’s the image generated, showing the two signals (top) and the two ways to do the correlation (`correlate(y1, y2)` vs `correlate(y2, y1)`, bottom).

[image: Data and correlation]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer it was very helpful. So I worked on my code and it reads my contrived data that I made with a delay of what ever number of frames I add (76 for this test). As I look to transition over to real recorded data what should I consider first? What filtering should I work on implementing? When I run this experiment with mics and playing the tone from a speaker I will get different numbers every time run, with some huge outliers. Any advice is great thanks - kyle

Comment: In your question, you said you were trying to find the distance between two mics. In your final application, will you still have control over what audio the two mics hear? What I mean is—if you know you're going to broadcast a tone, then by all means, you should correlate against a tone (or whatever signal you broadcast)—that’s how radar works and works very well! The longer the tone, the more accurate & well-resolved your delay estimate. (Or you could use a short signal if it has lots of bandwidth, like a chirp or a square waveform like BPSK).

Comment: If, however, you can’t control the audio that the two mics will pick up, and the distance estimation has to be done using ambient audio, hmm. That I don't know how to do off the top of my head.

Comment: You might be seeing spurious spikes in the correlation between the two audio channels because the sound is bouncing off of walls. Sometimes what people do is, they look for the first (earliest) peak in the correlation above some threshold, and say that’s their direct-path (speaker-to-mic), and all other spikes are multipath reflections.

Comment: Ahmed Fasih, in the final application I will be able to control what tone the source is. Ultimately I am trying to use the delay between the mics(possibly more than two) to calculate the arrival angle of the source. I thought this speed of sound test would be a good start. The white noise produces a nice peak in the correlation data, should I be using a square wave and having longer tests?

Comment: Nope, noise signals make excellent sonar waveforms, so if you have it working, then go for it. The term in the literature is “time-bandwidth product”—high resolution means high time-bandwidth product, which you can get by having narrow-band signal last a long time (e.g., a tone for a second) or a wideband signal last a brief interval (noise signal lasting 20 milliseconds, e.g.).

Comment: There’s a huge literature on acoustic angle-of-arrival estimation and source/receiver localization—[some work that inspired me back in the day](http://www.academia.edu/329587/Acoustic_Time_Delay_Estimation_and_Sensor_Network_Self-Localization_Experimental_Results), so hopefully you can find lots of info out there on how to do this. Though the papers usually leave out all the practical important details …

Answer (score 0):

A few more confusing examples from other websites, evaluated with
a procedure that's summarized by the function cnn .
The function rounded maybe equivalent to  the command round.

```py
'''

      Convolution , using 
      
      scipy.signals.fftconvolve.
      
      As this routine has various options, I shall check the results
     using information from various sources.  


'''

import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sg

def rounded(xv):
    sv = np.sign(xv)
    xv =  xv*1000
    xv = np.abs(xv)
    xv = xv +  500
    xv = xv.astype(int)
    xv = xv*sv
    xv =  xv/1000
    xv = xv.astype(int)
    return  xv


def cnn(vol,volf):
    vol=np.transpose(vol)
    volf=np.transpose(volf)
    volg=sg.fftconvolve(vol,volf, mode = 'valid')
    volg = rounded(volg)
    #volg=np.transpose(volg)
    return volg
    


# ------------------------------------------------------------------


# 10 10 10 0 0 0
# 10 10 10 0 0 0
# 10 10 10 0 0 0
# 10 10 10 0 0 0
# 10 10 10 0 0 0
# 10 10 10 0 0 0


# 1 0 -1
# 1 0 -1
# 1 0 -1

# 0 30 30 0
# 0 30 30 0
# 0 30 30 0
# 0 30 30 0

#



vol=[[10,10,10,10,10,10],[10,10,10,10,10,10],[10,10,10,10,10,10],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
vol=np.transpose(vol)
print("  ")
print(vol)
print('   ')

volf=[[-1,-1,-1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
volf=np.transpose(volf)
print(volf)
print('   ')


# mode = full valid  same

volg=sg.fftconvolve(vol,volf, mode = 'valid')
#volg=np.transpose(volg) # usually not required.

volg = rounded(volg)

print(volg)
# With slightly altered kernel, the result is true.
# should be
#[[0,30,30,0],[0,30,30,0],[0,30,30,0],[0,30,30,0]]

# original volf  =[[-1,-1,-1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]] , prior to adjustment or translate.

# https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/12/guide-convolutional-neural-network-cnn/


# From same website .

# 3 0 1 2 7 4
# 1 5 8 9 3 1
# 2 7 2 5 1 3
# 0 1 3 1 7 8
# 4 2 1 6 2 8
# 2 4 5 2 3 9

# 1 0 -1
# 1 0 -1
# 1 0 -1

# result
# -5  -4  0  8 
# -10 -2  2  3
# 0   -2 -4 -7
# -3  -2 -3 -16


vol=[[3,1,2,0,4,2],[0,5,7,1,2,4],[1,8,2,3,1,5],[2,9,5,1,6,2],[7,3,1,7,2,3],[4,1,3,8,8,9]]
vol=np.transpose(vol)

print(" ....................... ")
print("  ")
print(vol)
print('   ')
volf=[[-1,-1,-1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
volf=np.transpose(volf)
print(volf)
print('   ')


# mode = full valid  same

volg=sg.fftconvolve(vol,volf, mode = 'valid')


volg = rounded(volg)

print(volg)
# The result is true, however the kernel is different than at the website.

# quit()

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# another example , from .
# https://insightsimaging.springeropen.com/articles/10.1007/s13244-018-0639-9

# 1 2 1 0 2
# 2 0 0 1 0
# 1 0 2 1 0
# 0 1 0 2 1
# 0 2 1 0 2

# 1 0 1
# 0 1 0
# 1 0 1

# result.
# 1 4 2 0 3
# 4 5 3 6 1
# 2 2 6 2 3
# 2 5 3 7 2
# 1 2 4 1 4


vol=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,2,1,0,0,0],[0,2,0,0,1,2,0],[0,1,0,2,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,2,0,0],[0,2,0,0,1,2,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
vol=np.transpose(vol)
print("  ")
print(vol)
print('   ')
volf=[[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]

volf=np.transpose(volf)
print(volf)
print('   ')

volg = sg.fftconvolve(vol,volf, mode = 'valid')

volg = rounded(volg)

print(volg)
print(" ..........<<  >>.......... ")

#  Same result after applying rounded .

#quit()

# without padding .

# 1 2 1 0 2
# 2 0 0 1 0
# 1 0 2 1 0
# 0 1 0 2 1
# 0 2 1 0 2     

# 1 0 1
# 0 1 0
# 1 0 1

#  result
# 5 3 6
# 2 6 2
# 5 3 7    




vol=[[1,2,1,0,0],[2,0,0,1,2],[1,0,2,0,1],[0,1,1,2,0],[2,0,0,1,2]]
vol=np.transpose(vol)
print("  ")
print(vol)
print('   ')
volf=[[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]
volf=np.transpose(volf)
print(volf)
print('   ')

volg = sg.fftconvolve(vol,volf, mode = 'valid')


volg = rounded(volg)

print(volg)

#  Same result after applying rounded .



#quit()





# ----------------------------- valid ----------------------------------

#  Trying another example, from
# https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/convolutional-neural-networks-cnn-explained-step-by-step-69137a54e5e7

# 1 1 1 0 0
# 0 1 1 1 0
# 0 0 1 1 1
# 0 0 1 1 0
# 0 1 1 0 0

# 1 0 1
# 0 1 0
# 1 0 1  

 
# 4 3 4
# 2 4 3 
# 2 3 4 
 

 
vol=[[1,1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0]]
vol=np.transpose(vol)
print("  ")
print(vol)
print('   ')
volf=[[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]
volf=np.transpose(volf)
print(volf)
print('   ')

volg = sg.fftconvolve(vol,volf, mode = 'valid')
volg=np.transpose(volg) # Notice syntax for this procedure . 
volg = rounded(volg)
print(volg)
#  This is correct, however having to take the transpose of volg is
# unexpected and differs from most of the other examples.

#quit()


# ....................................................



# Yet another example, using previous method .

# https://www.deeplearningwizard.com/deep_learning/practical_pytorch/pytorch_convolutional_neuralnetwork/

# 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 0 2 2 0 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 2 2 2 0
# 0 2 0 0 2 0 0
# 0 0 0 0 2 0 0
# 0 0 2 2 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

# 1 1 1
# 0 0 0
# 0 0 0  

 
# 0 0 0 0 0 
# 4 4 2 0 0  
# 0 2 4 6 4 
# 2 2 2 2 2
# 0 0 2 2 2

vol=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,2,0,2,0,0,0],[0,2,0,0,0,2,0],[0,0,2,0,0,2,0],[0,0,2,2,2,0,0],[0,0,2,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
vol=np.transpose(vol)
print("  ")
print(vol)
print('   ')
volf=[[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]
volf=np.transpose(volf)
print(volf)
print('   ')

volg = sg.fftconvolve(vol,volf, mode = 'valid')
 
volg = rounded(volg)
print(volg)
#  this is correct, however volf is reversed.


#quit()
# .....................................................

# https://victorzhou.com/blog/intro-to-cnns-part-1/


# 0  50 0  29
# 0  80 31 2
# 33 90 0  75
# 0  9  0  95

# -1 0 1
# -2 0 2
# -1 0 1

#  29 -192
# -35 -22

vol=[[0,0,33,0],[50,80,90,9],[0,31,0,0],[29,2,75,95]]
vol=np.transpose(vol)
print(" ...............<<<<< ")
print(vol)
print('   ')
volf=[[1,2,1],[0,0,0],[-1,-2,-1]]
volf=np.transpose(volf)
print(volf)
print('   ')
volg = sg.fftconvolve(vol,volf, mode = 'valid')

volg = rounded(volg)
print(volg.astype(int))
#  this is correct, however volf is top row is reversed with bottom row.
# --------------------------------------------------------
#
#  To summarize, the function cnn is mostly correct for the examples
# that I found upon the web, when one enters the data values in the
# format shown .
#
```